# Does a Linux LiveCD expose you to the same viruses, malware, etc that are already present on the computer?

Tags: linux, livecd

If I were to run a Linux LiveCD regardless of the underlying operating system I am running, am I subject to the same problems I can run into when using the installed operating system? What are the limitations of a LiveCD when security is paramount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Firstly viruses are often platform specific. Secondly, the livecd is running off ram, and the base system is read-only, with any changes either being ignored, or on a overlay file system.

The installed OS affects the livecd in no way at all.

If security is the main consideration, livecds are perfect - you can verify that they're not tampered with, and if you turn off the system all data are lost.

Comment: What do you mean by `on a overlay file system`? Also what about what Keltari mentioned?

Comment: [UnionFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) is an example of a overlay filesystem. As for what Keltari mentioned, lets say you had a virus that was aware of your specific livecd, *and* could run on it (perhaps its written in java!) and managed to execute - then you'd have the virus affecting your current livecd session, change things on the internal storage (assuming it was mounted) and do the usual virusy things. However, outside hypothetical viruses, there's no practical virus that can do that. Most focus on windows since its the most common OS, though OS X viruses are popping up

Comment: Thanks. What about hardware specific spyware/malware?

Comment: This could be a separate question but I don't follow what it means by `It allows files and directories of separate file systems, known as branches, to be transparently overlaid, forming a single coherent file system`. So if I have a LiveCD which would be the branch assuming Windows is installed on the harddrive?

Comment: no. The main file system is the read only FS on the livecd. the branches are the changes made in the local session.

Comment: Thanks. I take it that `FS` refers to file system?

Comment: yeah it does. And yeah, this is pretty much seperate question territory at this point

Comment: Thanks. What are your thoughts on hardware specific malware or spyware and how it affects LiveCDs?

Comment: er.. there's no such thing as far as i know. so... no, it wouldn't affect the livecd. even boot sector viruses wouldn't affect a livecd.

Comment: Really? So if I have a keyboard that had a chip such as the one at amecisco.com/faq_hardwarekeylogger.htm, the LiveCD or anything I do in that session e.g. access secure sites with my password, etc would not be affected?

Comment: key loggers are NOT viruses. Its a function of the hardware in question, even if its not legitimate. If you suspect your keyboard, i'd suggest using a on screen keyboard, or immediately switching to a keyboard that's not compromised this way.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The liveCD itself is safe from getting infected by viruses.  No virus could get written to it.

However...

lets say the internal hard disk has a virus.  You could access the internal hard drive and its infected data.  Depending on the virus and how it operates, you could activate the virus.  It could affect how your LiveCD OS operates in *that particular session*, as well is infecting more data on your internal storage and the internet.